# Is this a memory leak of deleting base class pointer, and how to make it right

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, casting

Does the following case has memory leak? I suppose in foo(), the `delete *e` only sees the base part of the object. What about `*e = NULL`, is this refers to the Base object as well?

Sorry to mention, I used gcc4.4.7.

What is the good way of doing it? Any suggestion is appreciate!

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual bool valid() { return true; }
}

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() {}
    ~Derived() {}
    bool valid() { return false; }
}

void foo(Base** e)
{
    if((*e)->valid() {
        cout << "is valid";
    }   
    else{
        cout<< " not valid";
        delete *e;
        *e = NULL;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Derived* d = new Derived;
    Base* cast_d = static_cast<Base*>(d);
    foo(&cast_d);
}
```

Comment: That's what the *virtual* destructor is for.

Comment: Is it a leak? No.  Does it even compile?  No. Change `virtual valid() { return true; }` to `virtual bool valid() { return true; }`, and `valid() { return false; }` to `bool valid() { return false; }` Also, you don't need the `static_cast` (though it does work), you can directly assign a derived object pointer to a base pointer.

Comment: `*e = nullptr` (you should prefer a keyword over a macro...) just sets a pointer - no memory (other than the pointer's location itself) involved at all, thus no memory leak possible either (provided you deleted the object pointed to before, if this was the last pointer pointing to, just as in your example).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for pointing out the compiling error. Sorry I did not try to compile this code as I just want this for demo purpose. Also with gcc4.4.7, the static_cast is needed, otherwise compiling error "expecting Base** but giving Derived**". I guess this is because I used Base** rather than Base*.

Comment: @werk: I was referring to the assignment of `cast_d`, not the calling of `foo()`. Yes, since `foo()` takes a `Base**`, you need a `Base*` variable, but since `Derived` derives from `Base`, you can use `Base* cast_d = d;`, no `static_cast` is needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeauThanks! Got your point! Also I modified the code for the return type of `valid()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not at all a memory leak. When we delete a base class pointer if the base class pointer is holding the address of a derive class object it will first call derived class destructor if that is declared virtual. That is the reason why we have virtual destructor but not virtual constructor in C++. If we are using a Base class pointer to store the address of various derived classes pointers we should always declare the derived class destructor as virtual so that memory release should done in correct order.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

In the code there is no memory leak

the virtual destructor, allows any derived class to be properly destroyed.

If a Base * was passed into foo, it would not get destroyed, so it may leak .  But that is not in the code presented.

Comment: Re: "so it may leak" -- yes, and it may well do other nasty things. Deleting an object of a derived type through a pointer to the base type when the base type does not have a virtual destructor means that the behavior of your program is undefined.